# Unordered List not appearing properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ListItem from './ListItem.js';
import AddItem from './AddItem.js';
const uuidv4 = require('uuid');

class List extends Component {

  render() {
    var name = this.props.name;
    var items = this.props.items;

if (items.length > 0) {
  return (
    <div id={name} key={uuidv4()}>
      <h3>{name} List</h3>
        <ul>
        {items.map(function(item) {
          return (
                <li key={uuidv4()}><ListItem item={item} key={uuidv4()} /></li>
          )
        })}
        </ul>
      <AddItem idName={name} addItem={this.props.addItem.bind(this)} />
    </div>
  )
}

return (
  <div id={name} key={uuidv4()}>
    <h3>{name} List</h3>
    <AddItem idName={name} addItem={this.props.addItem.bind(this)} />
  </div>
)

  }
}

export default List;
```

In JSX I am trying to create a ListItem react component that returns some bolded text in a span element. But I also want the ListItem Component to appear as an unordered list, however, it appears like the image below.

List 1 List is the header of the list, and each Item (Item 1, Item 2, Item3) is the individual text returned by the ListItem component. And the form on the bottom is the location to enter a new item (ListItem component).

[image]

Comment: Could you please try to apply " li " css property --> display: list-item;

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with the rendered HTML and any CSS you have used. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338537/215552) to do this (the icon on the toolbar looks like `<>` in a page).

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
return (
<div>
 <h3>{name} List</h3>
  <ul>
       {items.map(item=><li><ListItem  key={item.uuidv4} item={item} /></li>)}
  </ul>
</div>

)
```